# Find matching records from multiple table using SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a master table which contains all company details. In master table all data are proper. I usually receive data in excel with company name and employee details.

Using SSIS , I used to import complete excel data to new table into a database. But in excel the company names are not proper. My requirement is based on matching company name need to find employee details. When I do joins with Master table which has proper company name and new Table, that time I fetch only exact matching records based exact company name matching.

For example, in master table I have company name as ABC India Private limited , but in new table the company name is ABC pvt. Ltd. . when I do joins based on company name, this will not match the company name and wont give employee details for this company. But my requirement is I should able get the employee details those Company names are matching at least only company name ABC in both table with irrespective of private limited or pvt. Ltd. . How to write SQL Query for this.

TO understand more please find the example-

### MasterData Table

### CompanyName

```
ABC India Private Limited
XYZ RAK Private Limited
PQR XRK Private Limited
```

### NewTable

```
EmpName|CompanyName|Age|Designation
HarishP|ABC pvt. Ltd.|30|Director
Rupeshj|XYZ RAK Ltd.|25|IT Head
RajeshK|PQR XRK Pvt.|45|Engineer
```

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server and PL/SQL here. What RDBMS are you *really* using? SQL Server uses T-SQL, not PL/SQL; Oracle uses PL/SQL.

Comment: As for your question, the answer is fix the data. `'ABC India Private Limited'` and `'ABC pvt. Ltd.` are nothing alike. The most they share is the first 3 characters.

Comment: In case you are limited to fix the data for some reason, you could also use a mapping table to associate different company names to a unique company. However, this is not ideal and difficult to maintain when possible faults grow.

Comment: And what would happen if "ABC Malaysia Pvt" existed? Or "ABC Mumbai Pvt"? Names are often very, VERY similar. Oversimplified sample data can easily lead you in the wrong direction. When a company name changes (which happens occasionally), what do you do? I can easily foresee a need for a mapping process.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely not possible using Sql server query as you don't know your data pattern. As you are using SSIS , You should solve this issue using **"Fuzzy Lookup"** in SSIS. And this will be your right approach.
For help regards **Fuzzy Lookup**, you can look [this URL](https://www.sqlshack.com/fuzzy-lookup-transformations-in-ssis/)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MasterData(CompanyName nvarchar(255))
> CREATE TABLE NewTable (EmpName nvarchar(255),CompanyName varchar(255),Age int,Designation varchar(255))
> INSERT INTO MasterData(CompanyName) VALUES('ABC India Private Limited'),
> ('XYZ RAK Private Limited'),
> ('PQR XRK Private Limited')
> INSERT INTO NewTable(EmpName,CompanyName,Age,Designation)
> VALUES('HarishP','ABC pvt. Ltd.',30,'Director'),
> ('Rupeshj','XYZ RAK Ltd.',25,'IT Head'),
> ('RajeshK','PQR XRK Pvt.',45,'Engineer')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT N.EmpName,N.Age,N.Designation,M.*
> FROM MasterData AS M
> INNER JOIN NewTable AS N
>   ON N.CompanyName LIKE CONCAT('%', LEFT(M.CompanyName ,3), '%')
> ```

> ```
> EmpName | Age | Designation | CompanyName              
> :------ | --: | :---------- | :------------------------
> HarishP |  30 | Director    | ABC India Private Limited
> Rupeshj |  25 | IT Head     | XYZ RAK Private Limited  
> RajeshK |  45 | Engineer    | PQR XRK Private Limited
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9a3dcd3d1fbaa46de1b5dc2128ec479)*

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged it as PL/SQL which reads as "Oracle", see if this helps.

If you use `utl_match` package, you can calculate "similarity" which shows how similar strings are (from 0 to 100). Cross-join of those two tables shows this:

```
SQL> with
  2  master (company_name) as
  3    (select 'ABC India Private Limited' from dual union all
  4     select 'XYZ RAK Private Limited'   from dual union all
  5     select 'PQR XRK Private Limited'   from dual
  6    ),
  7  new_table (emp_name, company_name, age, designation) as
  8    (select 'HarishP', 'ABC pvt. Ltd.', 30, 'Director' from dual union all
  9     select 'Rupeshj', 'XYZ RAK Ltd.' , 25, 'IT Head'  from dual union all
 10     select 'RajeshK', 'PQR, XRK Pvt.', 45, 'Engineer' from dual
 11    )
 12  select n.emp_name,
 13         n.company_name new_cname,
 14         m.company_name,
 15         n.age,
 16         n.designation,
 17         utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(lower(m.company_name), lower(n.company_name)) sim
 18  from master m cross join new_table n
 19  order by n.company_name, m.company_name;

EMP_NAM NEW_CNAME     COMPANY_NAME                     AGE DESIGNAT        SIM
------- ------------- ------------------------- ---------- -------- ----------
HarishP ABC pvt. Ltd. ABC India Private Limited         30 Director         77
HarishP ABC pvt. Ltd. PQR XRK Private Limited           30 Director         47
HarishP ABC pvt. Ltd. XYZ RAK Private Limited           30 Director         52
RajeshK PQR, XRK Pvt. ABC India Private Limited         45 Engineer         45
RajeshK PQR, XRK Pvt. PQR XRK Private Limited           45 Engineer         84
RajeshK PQR, XRK Pvt. XYZ RAK Private Limited           45 Engineer         58
Rupeshj XYZ RAK Ltd.  ABC India Private Limited         25 IT Head          47
Rupeshj XYZ RAK Ltd.  PQR XRK Private Limited           25 IT Head          54
Rupeshj XYZ RAK Ltd.  XYZ RAK Private Limited           25 IT Head          83

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, it is obvious - when we look at it - which `company_name` pairs are OK and which are not. In this case, acceptable limit is e.g. `75` so if we include it into the `where` clause, we get:

```
 <snip>
 12  select n.emp_name,
 13         n.company_name new_cname,
 14         m.company_name,
 15         n.age,
 16         n.designation,
 17         utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(lower(m.company_name), lower(n.company_name)) sim
 18  from master m join new_table n
 19    on utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(lower(m.company_name), lower(n.company_name)) > 75
 20  order by n.company_name, m.company_name;

EMP_NAM NEW_CNAME     COMPANY_NAME                     AGE DESIGNAT        SIM
------- ------------- ------------------------- ---------- -------- ----------
HarishP ABC pvt. Ltd. ABC India Private Limited         30 Director         77
RajeshK PQR, XRK Pvt. PQR XRK Private Limited           45 Engineer         84
Rupeshj XYZ RAK Ltd.  XYZ RAK Private Limited           25 IT Head          83

SQL>
```

Or, prettier:

```
 <snip>
 12  select n.emp_name,
 13         m.company_name,
 14         n.age,
 15         n.designation
 16  from master m join new_table n
 17    on utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(lower(m.company_name), lower(n.company_name)) > 75
 18  order by n.company_name, m.company_name;

EMP_NAM COMPANY_NAME                     AGE DESIGNAT
------- ------------------------- ---------- --------
HarishP ABC India Private Limited         30 Director
RajeshK PQR XRK Private Limited           45 Engineer
Rupeshj XYZ RAK Private Limited           25 IT Head

SQL>
```

---

However, will it work correctly for ALL your cases? Most probably not. Depends on quality of garbage you get as input.